# Delete Ubuntu 32 bit and Install 64 bit Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 bit installed along side Windows 8.1. And now I want to delete/uninstall 32 bit Ubuntu OS and install 64 bit Ubuntu 16 along side Windows 8.1. I don't want to lose my data. Is it possible?

Comment: "yes" would be the only correct answer to this.

Comment: If your question instead would be "How do I do this?". You create backups of anything important and restore those backups when you installed your operating system.

Comment: Yeah of course, what about along side windows. If windows crashed while installing ?

Comment: Windows can't crash while installing Ubuntu because Windows is not running.  Unless you're trying to install Ubuntu with WUBI?

Comment: @rinzwind and Dorian, thanks for the valuable suggestion.

Comment: Technically your boot can be killed during a reinstall but there are guides out there on how to reinstall or fix grub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it move all data from Ubuntu drive to mounted drives. Like your documents, pictures, downloads, desktop content etc. Easier way would be to then wipe your 32 bit install and go ahead installing your 64 bit version.

Make sure that you check where applications like Thunderbird, Firefox etc store their backup and take them to a safe place as well.